# In Plotly (python), how to disconnect a lines when no values?

Tags: python, plotly

In Plotly (Python), I would like to disconnect a line when there is no value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(2,12), index=pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', freq='d', periods=10), columns=['A'])
idx = [1,2, 4,5, 7,8]

fig = go.Figure()
line = go.Scatter(x=df.index[idx], y=df['A'][idx])
fig.add_trace(line)
fig.show()
```

In this example, I expected to plot three separate lines as `idx` is not continuous numbers, but it plots one single line.

How to gap when `idx` has missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding in a column, keeping the desired values for A and adding a null value for segments you don't want plotted.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(range(2,12), index=pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', freq='d', periods=10), columns=['A'])
idx = [1,2, 4,5, 7,8]

df['a'] = np.where(df.reset_index().index.isin(idx), df['A'], np.nan)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['a']))

fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Alternatively, if you don't want to add a new column, you could just add the trace as

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=np.where(df.reset_index().index.isin(idx), df['A'], np.nan)))
```